# Problem with UHD and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, graphics, monitor

I have strange problem with system totally freezing up.

Few days ago i got a new monitor, Samsung U32J590 32", not the best
but hey, it has pretty nice resolution and i got it for very good price.

I cant 100% say the freezing is because of this, but it sure seems to happen now, and i have no memory of it happening before. Surely i have had my OS freezing, but usually it's because i did something stupid or created infinite loop etc..

But this is different as it seems to trigger semi reliably with trying to utilize the monitor.

for example. i had total system halt twice, in span of 10min when i tried to set backgroud which was 4k picture. First time everything halted instantly.
Second time i tried to recreate the problem by just booting up and trying again and sure enough, i witnessed my mouse moving for about a second after that, and then full system stop.

Hardware is

- Core i5-9600K
- Asus PRIME Z370-P II Intel Z370
- Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4 3200 MHz 16 Gt
- nvidia GTX 970

GPU is not the newest available, but as a developer with another PC for gaming i really dont have to much use for better GPU and i would assume 970 to be beefy enough to handle browsing, youtube and few windows of intelliJ's

Please, ask if you need more info
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

So, i removed my nvidia drivers and re-installed drivers from nvidia repo, driver version 410

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-410
```

be aware, you might need a different driver for different card and or in future.
Anyhow, this solved it for me on GTX 970